# Identifying stake and unstake transactions for a given stake account

Tags: jsonrpc-api, staking

Suppose I run a validator and am interested in historical staking and un-staking transactions with my validator. I have a list of all the stake accounts for my validator. From that I'm able to get lists of transactions.

Going through this list and calling [`getTransaction`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction) for each, how do I distinguish staking transactions from un-staking transactions? Or both from any other type of transaction (if those are even possible for a stake account)?

Could we look at the instructions that have executed in the transaction? Which instructions would only be there for a staking transaction and which for an un-staking transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the first part right! If you call `getTransaction` with the `jsonParsed` return option, the transaction `type` will tell you exactly what kind of transaction it is.

For example, if you look at the third instruction in this transaction https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5UNXnUJHqETdLHGxuSeMf6nQBZvtHQ3oL7PsHozxuFvCXTRBWHMSaA3E4bZ8ndAF2FACdDfduJgW88bG1AkWtQXH and click "Raw", you'll see the following:

```
{
  "info": {
    "clockSysvar": "SysvarC1ock11111111111111111111111111111111",
    "stakeAccount": "7vRC96mHe7ziiu3TNyCWCveYtgQUkQUFDyFxvZk77NMT",
    "stakeAuthority": "AhbkRLfEuL5zV5gbooQzcDP7dZLBWK5En3mPVixs34yb",
    "stakeConfigAccount": "StakeConfig11111111111111111111111111111111",
    "stakeHistorySysvar": "SysvarStakeHistory1111111111111111111111111",
    "voteAccount": "9xSvmMmFmG9atApxNDH5MY3pxKdicMKAGf7dNrwbTV1q"
  },
  "type": "delegate"
}
```

So from the `type`, you can see if it's `delegate` or `deactivate` to check for the two instruction types that you care about.